# If else if trouble

Tags: javascript, if-statement

i am having trouble getting my if, else if, else statement to work, there must be some error with the syntax because the whole code wont work. I tried adding/removing the semi colens after each statement but it still didnt work. I originally had 6 if statements which worked but cant perform the task properly but i know the conditional statements work. Here is my code

```
if (pislandinfo != null){
    alert("pi")
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon)
    placeMarker1(myLatlng, pislandinfo)
    map.setCenter(myLatlng)
    map.setZoom(Number(zoom))
}
else if (eislandinfo != null){
    alert("ei")
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon)
    placeMarker1(myLatlng, eislandinfo)
    map.setCenter(myLatlng)
    map.setZoom(Number(zoom))
}
else if (wislandinfo != null){
    alert("wi")
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon)
    placeMarker1(myLatlng, wislandinfo)
    map.setCenter(myLatlng)
    map.setZoom(Number(zoom))
}
else if (pmooringinfo != null){
    alert("pm")
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon)
    placeMarker1(myLatlng, pmooringinfo)
    map.setCenter(myLatlng)
    map.setZoom(Number(zoom))
}
else if (emooringinfo != null){
    alert("em")
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon)
    placeMarker1(myLatlng, emooringinfo)
    map.setCenter(myLatlng)
    map.setZoom(Number(zoom))
}
else (wmooringinfo != null){
    alert("wm")
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon)
    placeMarker1(myLatlng, wmooringinfo)
    map.setCenter(myLatlng)
    map.setZoom(Number(zoom))
}
```

Comment: it is incorrect for your last else statement to have a conditional expression.  remove '(wmooringinfo != null)' or make it an else if

Answer (score 0):

You cannot include an evaluation in the final else:

`else (wmooringinfo != null){`

That is invalid.  Perhaps you intended this

`else if (wmooringinfo != null){`

What language is this?  And what is the context?
Answers to these questions will make it easier to help you.